# vim player "u" command doesnt work without close/reopen

Tags: vim

This is my starting text

making the command

```
4dw
```

[image]

output

[image]

now to go back to the previous state I type in:

```
u
```

ouptut:

[image]

it overlaps the current text ... instead of actually undoing it
When I tab out now with `ctrl y` and go back in with `fg` it looks like at the begin ... so it is only a visual bug - which is kind of annoying that I have to tab out everytime I undo something ... is there an option or a known bug / issue / workaround for this?

Comment: Which vim and which platform?

Comment: hmm dont really know - just installed it with apt-get install vim-tiny (or something simliar) 

platform: Ubuntu newest version

Comment: maybe it&#39;s caused be a custom keymapping or plugin...?! maybe you try it without your settings via: vim -u NONE

Comment: have no plugins installed or anything - only vim installed without any additions .. but I log in to the remote machine with putty

Comment: Try hitting Ctrl+L (note, the L isnt uppercase, I just didn't want you to mistake it for an I) to reload the terminal screen and see if that also corrects the visual bug. If this works then I would say it probably is a visual bug and could maybe be fixed by switching terminal emulators. It is a pretty strange bug though. If you do find an answer, please do post it.